# Why does Result return the correct status code only in the response body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Whenever I return any `Result` it is always 200 status code. For example check this code

```
public async Task<IResult> Login(UserLoginDto login)
{
    var user = await _userMgr.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var result = await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, login.Password, false, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var token = await _authRepo.GenerateToken(user);
            _logger.LogInformation("User with email: {Email} is logged in ", user.Email);
            return Results.Ok(new { user.Email,  Token = token });
        }
        else
        {
            return Results.Unauthorized();
        }
    }
    return Results.NotFound();
}
```

always returns the correct status code inside the response body only and 200Ok in the response header. How do i fix this weird behavior? i have looked into the .net 6 documentation but to no avail.

UPDATE#1

this is the middlewere

```
var app = builder.Build();
await app.SystemInit(builder.Configuration);

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//todo: disable cors for production env
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseCors(myAllowSpecificOrigins);

}

app.UseHealthChecks("/api/healthy");

// app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Strongly suggests that something is taking the IResult and inappropriately wrapping it. Could be some misconfigured/misauthored middleware, a proxy of some sort, etc.

Comment: You are correct. But the middle is boilerplate. I will add my middlewere in my post

Comment: @Ryan Why don't use return NotFound();

Comment: Hi and welcome. Microsoft has very good documentation. Please read it: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asynchronous-action-2)

Comment: have a checked what value is returned in result by placing a break point?

Comment: To add a bit on what @Serge said, you should never give any information on why the authentication failed as this could be used by a potential attacker. This method should only return either : Ok or Unauthorized.

Comment: For the question itself, I would look into how you are calling this method, what tool are you using ? Is it part of another call ?

Comment: I have tested Result in an empty project and it works fine. I have tried to figure the problem, but the codebase is new to me and i decided to go with ActionResult. I will try to figure it in future and update the question. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why all the result method will return 200 inside the MVC action is it is used for minimal api not for MVC action method.

Th [result.notfound method](https://%20https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/39f0e0b8f40b4754418f81aef0de58a9204a1fe5/src/Http/Http.Results/src/Results.cs#L522) will build a [notfound.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/39f0e0b8f40b4754418f81aef0de58a9204a1fe5/src/Http/Http.Results/src/NotFound.cs#L16) object and this  notfound.cs object contains a executeasync method which is used to build the httpresponse.

Since you just return the Iresult instead of using the ExecuteAsync mehtod, so it will just return the json object to the client instead of calling the ExecuteAsync method to write a new response.

The right way to return the status codes inside the MVC action method you should use IActionResult's NotFound() method.

If you are using minimal API, you could use iresult like this:

```
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () => Results.NotFound());
```